# How do I scrape data into a spreadsheet directly from Indeed?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am working on a project where I scrape data from indeed search results. I want to collect the title of the listing, the company name, the location, and the description. Right now, I am able to go to the next page by modifying the URL, but after scraping all of the pages, it does not export correctly into my .csv file. Please let me know what you think!

Here is my current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

MAX_PAGE_NUM = 3
MAX_PAGE_DIG = 2
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/nzalle/Downloads/chromedriver")

with open('results.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write("Title, Company Name, Location, Description \n")

for i in range (0, MAX_PAGE_NUM + 1):
    page_num = (MAX_PAGE_DIG - len(str(i))) * str(i) + "0"
    url = "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=EHS&l=Arizona&start=" + page_num

    driver.get(url)

    Title = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "jobtitle", " " ))]')
    CompanyName = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "company", " " ))] | //*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "company", " " ))]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "turnstileLink", " " ))]')
    Location = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "accessible-contrast-color-location", " " ))]')
    Description = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[(@id = "resultsCol")]//li')

    num_page_items = len(Title)
    with open('results.csv', 'a') as f:
        for i in range(num_page_items):
            f.write(Title[i].text + "," + CompanyName[i].text + "," + Location[i].text + "," + Description[i].text + "\n")
```

Comment: `...it does not export correctly into my .csv file.` - are you satisfied that the data you scraped (`Title`,`CompanyName`,`Location`,`Description`) is correct? If so you should provide a [mre] that includes some sample data.

Comment: I am happy with my header, but it only scrapes three of the search results

Comment: Please read why a [Can someone help me? is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.